# How can I make my Cursor survive an orientation change?

Tags: android, configuration, rotation, android-cursor

I am trying to make my app rotation friendly, but I am having some problems saving the cursor.

The cursor holds about 13k+ rows of data displayed in a `ListView`, and thus would take quite a while if I would do a requery every time the configuration changes.  In my `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`, I am returning my Cursor and then retrieving it through `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`.

However, my retrieved cursor seems to be closed already, and thus my adapter cannot render the list anymore.  From what I understand, the cursor was closed since `onDestroy()` automatically closes all cursors.

I save the Cursor like this:

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return myCursor;
}
```

And retrieve it like this:

```
myCursor = (Cursor)getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
if (myCursor == null) {
    // Do some stuff here (access DB, etc)
} else { // we are returning from configuration change
    // Feed the cursor to the adapter
}
```

I am pasting the stack trace if someone wants to look at it:

```
01-25 16:57:45.637: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12976): android.database.StaleDataException: Access closed cursor
    01-25 16:57:45.637: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12976):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:217)
    01-25 16:57:45.637: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12976):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
    01-25 16:57:45.637: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12976):     at com.test.sample.helper.DictionaryAdapter.bindView(DictionaryAdapter.java:35)
[........More ListView-related errors here..........]
```

I stepped through the code and I found out that as far as `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`, the cursor is still open, but after getting it through `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` it is already closed.

How can I make my Cursor survive the orientation change?  Thank you for the help!

**EDIT:**
Based on Romain's answer, I commented out all my `startManagingCursor()`s. I should have connected the dots and thought about it! Anyway, my app now survives one rotation, but flipping it back to the original orientation still crashes it. Continuing my debugging and will let you know what I find out.

**EDIT2:**
I think I may have found what is causing the new errors. I have implemented a `FilterQueryProvider` which returns a new Cursor.  What I did was assign the results of that filter to my original Cursor.  Seems to work so far.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by " assign the results of that filter to my original Cursor" in edit 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using a managed cursor. Managed cursors are automatically closed when the Activity is destroyed. You should switch to an unmanaged Cursor.

Comment: Yes! I am using a managed cursor. I tried to comment out all my `startManagingCursor()`, and so far the app has survived changing from portrait to landscape. But changing it back again to portrait crashes the app (Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to acquire a reference on a close SQLiteClosable). Will try to debug more, but this answer definitely helped! Thanks Romain! I will report back on whatever happens to my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this attribute in your activity tag in the manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

it will resolve this

no need to implement anything else

:)
It helped me though

Comment: Hi Javanator! As much as possible I would like to have the "correct" way of handling the change. According to the documentation, that should be the last resort. ;) So let's hope I can fix this. :D

Comment: I am waiting for your result. this simple solution once resolved a complex problem of mine.
This also is not a shortcut to anything. it just tell the Activity Manager not to call the onCreate again.As far as i know. :)

Comment: This, according to the [documentation][1]: `Note: Handling the configuration change yourself can make it much more difficult to use alternative resources, because the system does not automatically apply them for you. This technique should be considered a last resort and is not recommended for most applications.` Will let you know how I resolve this. :) [1]http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject